# Applying the equation array to a limit

Tags: math-mode, equations

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, I mostly use it to take calculus notes that I can actually read because relying on my handwriting has not worked very well in the past. I was wondering if there was a way to make `\lim` work in a way like the `eqnarray` environment does. Like when you write:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
2(2)^2 &=& 2(4) \\
&=& 8
\end{eqnarray}
```

then it aligns all the answers. Limits don't necessarily state an equation relation, but it would still be convenient to type `\lim_{x \to 0}` once and align all the modifications made to the equation it applies to, to declutter the actual note page and speed up the note taking process.

Basically, I want to write

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x \to 0} &=& x^{5x} \\
&=& e^{\ln x^{5x}}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

except without any equal signs.

Comment: Do you also want the equations to be numbered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, clarify your question with small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` on beginning and `\end{document}` on the end and on its result show to us, what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the aligning environments offered by the package `amsmath` (which are better than `eqnarray` anyway).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
2(2)^2 &= 2(4) \\
       &= 8
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} {} & x^{5x} \\
                  & e^{\ln x^{5x}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```